# How to disable HTTP 1.0 protocol in Apache?

Tags: http

HTTP 1.0 has security weakness related to session hijacking. Is there a way to disable it by using the `mod_rewrite` module?

Comment: What weakness are you talking about? The premise seems flawed, and it makes very little sense to forbid "HTTP/1.0" requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ensure to load mod_rewrite module in httpd.conf file
2. Enable RewriteEngine directive as following and add Rewrite condition to allow       only HTTP 1.1

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !HTTP/1.1$

   RewriteRule .* - [F]
   ```

Comment: This woud also forbid HTTP/2...

Answer (score 5):

You may try this mod_rewrite, this worked for me.
  Here the server would try to respond with a 403-Forbidden response code.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.0$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path-to-your-custom-403-error-page\.html$
RewriteRule .? - [F]
```