# Apache RewriteEngine config purpose

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

I ran into this snippet in an Apache config file that someone else wrote, but I'm not sure of the purpose. Could anyone explain what this is for?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !HTTP/1\.1$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/885724/how-to-disable-http-1-0-protocol-in-apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those directives reject (403 Forbidden) any request that is not HTTP/1.1. Many bots crawl with a HTTP/1.0 request header - so these will be blocked. All modern browsers will use HTTP/1.1 (*at least*). However, with HTTP/2.0 already here, these directives are arguably outdated and should not be used.

The `THE_REQUEST` server variable contains the initial request header of the form:

```
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
```

If you want to block HTTP/1.0 only then you could use something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.0$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```