# Restrict access via HTTP 0.9 and HTTP 1.0 on Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, http

Is it possible to block any access other than HTTP 1.1 and HTTP/2 on Apache, for all VirtualHosts?

I added the code below to apache2.conf, but I still see IP requests coming via HTTP 1.0

```
#Block HTTP 0.9
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/0\.9$
RewriteRule .* - [F]

#Block HTTP 1.0
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.0$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Already answered here: [885724](https://serverfault.com/questions/885724/)

Comment: Also afaik, there's no `HTTP/0.9` string. The lack of any HTTP/ string means HTTP 0.9.

Comment: @JoãoAlves This code seems to block everything that is different from HTTP 1.1, including HTTP/2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable HTTP 1.0 protocol in Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/885724/how-to-disable-http-1-0-protocol-in-apache)

Comment: The suggested answer  block everything that is different from HTTP 1.1, including HTTP/2. Keeping HTTP/2 as allowed is important.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple way to do it:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !HTTP/
RewriteRule .* - [R=451,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.0
RewriteRule .* - [R=451,L]
```

HTTP 0.9 requests are in the format `GET /` without any kind of HTTP/XX version indicator, so the first rule will catch them.  I've made the rule case sensitive so it will also catch clients who don't capitalize the "HTTP" properly, which shouldn't be a problem for legitimate clients; you can make it case-insensitive if you want but you'd probably want to make the second rule case-insensitive as well so HTTP1.0 traffic can't sneak by as "http/1.0" or similar.

You'll have to decide what kind of response code you want to send back.  In this example, I've used `R=451` to send back a `451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons` so I can spot these easily in the logs as Apache should never generate that error on its own.  (I tried using `418 I'm a teapot` but Apache doesn't currently allow it).

For simplicity, instead of using an `R=`, you can simply use `G` for `410 Gone` or `F` for `403 Forbidden`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !HTTP/
RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} HTTP/1\.0
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Caveats:

1. You will still see the requests in your log but you should see the appropriate response code.
2. If you use custom error pages, you may need additional `RewriteCond` statements so that the redirect doesn't trigger again when it tries to load the error page.
3. Other redirects could potentially get invoked before these redirects.  For example, if you put these redirects in global configuration, but also have an HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect in vhost configuration, the latter might get executed first.